# A specific SSRS hack - a customized design for the parameter bar

Tags: reporting-services

I have exhausted many options to implement the below design (link to page) in the ssrs parameter bar.  Have learned painfully that it is not easy to customize design...  Would someone perhaps have an ingenious hack?  I really appreciate if someone can me implement the below design (image on another site) into ssrs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off building a separate web app than trying to modify and rebuild the default parameter UI. Just design your app to collect parameters and pass them to the report and display it in an iframe blow. Alternatively, look into referencing the Reporting Services web service to render the report once you have the parameters.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa274396%28SQL.80%29.aspx